# Canonical url issue in magento

Tags: php, magento

My url key is looking like

```
http://localhost/twisted-throttle/denali-m7-dot-led-headlight-module-7-0-round-black-chrome
```

But in canonical looking like

```
http://localhost/twisted-throttle/catalog/product/view/_ignore_category/1/id/19333/s/denali-m7-dot-led-headlight-module-7-0-round-black-chrome/
```

This is wrong, canonical url same should be like url.
I am using Magento Enterprise 1.14.

Answer (score 0):

Please check 
In admin: SYSTEM >> CONFIG >> CATALOG >> SEARCH ENGINE OPTIMIZATION
And there are setting of it. Please check and do it as per your need it will display same as you want.
Hope this will help you.

Thanks